# Float behaving like int (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm practising using float and i made console application which should double the number user entered.For some reason,when i enter number like 1,25,program outputs 2 (likee its int,and not float) instead of 2,5.

Code (I use Microsoft Visual Studio):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

float racun(float x)
{
    return x * 2;
}

int main()
{
    float y;
    std::cin >> y;
    std::cout << racun(y) << std::endl;
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried entering, for example, `1.25`?

Comment: The first step in debugging this kind of problem is understanding your input. The code should display the value of `y` so that you can pin down more precisely where the problem is occurring. If the answer by @tadman is correct, showing the value of `y` would have shown you the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ is going to use "American" decimal notation by default, so `1,25` is interpreted as `1` not `1.25`.

You'll need to enter `1.25` or convert the `,` to a `.` before parsing.